# Ввод в поле с помощью Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет, тут такое дело, как с помощью js в поле вбивать допустим слово "Hello."?

Comment: js не молоток, лучше не вбивать  а присваивать 
`element.value="Hello.";`

Comment: для описанной вами задачи js не нужен, можно обойтись клавиатурой, руками и примитивной моторикой.

Comment: В том то  и дело нужно сделать скриптом

Comment: сложно представить себе скрипт который вбивает в какое то поле допустим привет. Возникает множество вопросов, что такое поле, что такое вбивать, каким образом скрипт узнает о слове которое необходимо вбивать, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById (id).value = "Hello";
// для textarea

document.getElementById (id).innerHTML = "Hello";
// для div
```